# Skeptics.SE Facebook page

Tags: discussion

As [requested](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1762/why-doesnt-skeptics-have-a-facebook-page) during the Skeptics election, we now have a Facebook page.

[image: Skeptics on Facebook]

https://www.facebook.com/skeptics.se

The page is maintained by the community, and is not officially endorsed by StackExchange.

Comment: Mods - if you "like" the page, I will make you admins... :-)

Comment: Already liked it, and shared it.  :)  By the way, the meta page doesn't have the social media sharing buttons?

Comment: @LarianLeQuella nope, since meta is very rarely something relevant outside the community. You can still grab the link and share it though.

Comment: No worries, I am getting the word out.  I have sent invites to skeptic "celebrities" although James Randii is beyond my reach, I did get some good names from my firends list.  Hope they "like" the page, as well as possibly swing by here.

Comment: As I side note, I've got an ad campaign making the page a bit more popular...

Comment: Need any help/reimbursement for that?  I can re-up that if it will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stack Exchange questions with no answer appear on an "Unanswered" list to attract more attention to them.

In meta-sites, like this one, sometimes questions, like this one, aren't really questions, and don't need this attention.

They are sometimes given fake answers, like this one, just so they don't appear on the "Unanswered" list.